# Events that make the same request run both success functions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have these two events that run based on different user actions:

```
$("#template_informations").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/marketing/gpnews/template",
        data: formData,
        dataType: "json",
        headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' }, 
        success: function(data) {
            $(".code").text(data.html);
        }
    });
});
```

This too:

```
$(document).on("click", "#test-template", function(event) {
    var formData = $("#template_informations").serialize();

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/marketing/gpnews/template",
      data: formData,
      success: function(data) {
          var test_field = $(".test-field");

          var textoHTML = decodeEntities(data.html);

          const div = document.createElement('div');

          const parser = new DOMParser();
          const parsedHTML = parser.parseFromString(textoHTML, 'text/html');

          div.appendChild(parsedHTML.documentElement);

          test_field.html(div);
        }
    });
})
```

The problem is that even when event 1 runs, the success function of event 2 also runs, and the same when event 2, which ends up triggering the event 1 function too.

How to resolve this?

Comment: Apparently you have some action that triggers to handlers. Yet you don't want that, however, what should happen instead? Which event should run?

Comment: Is `test-template`  is the id of the submit button?

Comment: why is the same ajax url giving 2 types of data? Could you please explain?

Comment: I have a form that has two buttons, one that submits it and the other that is a button with id test-template. The first event is for when the form is submitted, the second for when the button with id test-template is clicked.

Comment: What exactly is `#test-template`?  Please include enough HTML to reproduce the issue - see [mcve].  If it's a `<button id=..>` then it's *also* a *submit* button and will submit your form (thus hit the submit handler).   Change to `<button type='button' id=..>`

Answer (score -1):

[From your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77402200/events-that-make-the-same-request-run-both-success-functions/77402240#comment136455051_77402200): You have two submit buttons. Both will submit the form and thus trigger the submit event handler.

One has the id `test-template` which you want to run the `click` event handler but **not** the `submit` event handler. Currently it runs both. (You're making two different Ajax requests, not one request which triggers both `success` functions.)

The other submit button should trigger the `submit` event handler.

---

There are two approaches you could take.

## Prevent the default behaviour of the click

The default behaviour of a submit button is to submit the form. Preventing the default behaviour will prevent the submit event from firing.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#test-template", function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
```

## Don't use a submit button

Submit buttons are supposed to submit forms. If you don't use want to submit the form with the button, then don't use a submit button.

```
<button id="test-template" type="button">...</button>
```